# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - EB Extensions Not Working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

I've done this before a long time ago, but now it's not working... :)

I am trying to use EBExtensions in an ElasticBeanstalk application. I created a vanilla Elastic Beanstalk environment with no configuration beyond the defaults. I gave it an application version that had a directory structure like the following:

```
.ebextensions
  40testextension.config
app.js
other files
```

The important part is that I have a folder called .ebextensions at the root of my deployable artifact, which is where I believe it should be located.

The 40testextension.config file inside that file has the following contents:

```
files:
  "/home/ec2-user/myfile" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      # This is my file
      # with content
```

I uploaded that version when creating the environment, and the environment created successfully. But when I look for that file, it is not present. Furthermore, when do a recursive grep for that ebextension file name in the logs at /var/log, I only get one result:

```
./eb-activity.log:    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/.ebextensions/40testextension.config
```

Having looked at the logs, it seems that the file is present when the artifact gets pulled down to the host, but the ebextension never gives any indication of running.

What am I missing here? I've done this in the distant past and things have worked very nicely, but this time I can't seem to get the thing to be executed by the Beanstalk deploy lifecycle.

Comment: did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

try to run it with `-x Print commands and their arguments as they are executed` to debug and try to change the mode to `000777`.

```
files:
  "/home/ec2-user/myfile" :
    mode: "000777"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash

      set -xe
```